# Where should I put jars on a dataproc cluster so they can be used by gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark?

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I have an initialisation script that downloads a .jar from our local artefact repository and places it into `/usr/local/bin` on each node on the cluster. I can run it using

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster=my_cluster \
      --region=us-central1 --jar=file:///usr/local/bin/myjar.jar -- arg1 arg2
```

However I'd prefer it if my end users did not have to know the location of the jar.

Where can I put the .jar so that the location of it does not have to be specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For spark jobs, you should be able to just place your jarfiles in `/usr/lib/spark/jars` on all nodes to automatically be available on the classpath.

For a more general coverage, you could add your jars to `/usr/lib/hadoop/lib` instead; the hadoop lib directory is also automatically included into Spark jobs on Dataproc, and is where libraries such as the GCS connector jarfile reside. You can see the hadoop lib directory being included via the `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH` environment variable configured in `/etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh`.

If the desired behavior is still to specify using the `--jar` flag to specify a "main jar" instead of `--jars` to specify library jars that just provide classes, unfortunately there's currently no notion of a "working directory" on the cluster that would allow just specifying relative (instead of absolute) paths to the "main jar". However, there are two approaches that would have similar behavior:

1. Make the jarfiles local to the user's workspace from which jobs are being submitted - gcloud will then upload the jarfile at job-submission time into GCS and point the job at the jarfile when it runs in a job-specific directory. Note that this would cause duplicate uploads of the jarfile into GCS each time the job runs since it's always staging into a unique job directory; you'd have to `gcloud dataproc jobs delete` later on to clean up GCS space used by those jarfiles
2. (Preferred approach): Use the `--class` instead of the `--jar` argument for specifying what job to run after doing the steps above to make the jar available in the Spark classpath already. While the invocation of a classname is a bit more verbose, it still achieves the goal  of hiding details of jarfile location from the user.

For example, the classes used for "spark-shell" implementation are already on the classpath, so if you wanted to run a scala file as if you were running it through `spark-shell`, you could run:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster my-cluster \
    --class org.apache.spark.repl.Main \
    -- -i myjob.scala
```

Comment: I assume ${SPARK_HOME} returns /usr/lib/spark ?

Comment: Just tested that assumption, it’s a false assumption. Guess I’ll just hardcode /usr/lib/spark

Comment: Sorry @dennis-huo, I'm having difficulty getting this working. I am putting the jar in `/usr/lib/spark/jars` and I know that Spark knows about them because of log messages I see when I submit a job, however I'm still having to use the whole path in `gcloud dataproc jobs submit --cluster mycluster --jar file:///usr/lib/spark/jars/myjar.jar` What am I missing?

Comment: Oh, I missed the fact that you're using it as your "main jar", not just a library jar. Did you want users to still have to specify the jarfile name, but not the directory in which it resides? Or to submit a job without having to specify any jarfile at all?

Comment: Hi @dennis-huo. The former of those two things, happy for them to provide the jar name but don't want them to have to know where on the cluster node it resides. That just feels like it's exposing some of the inner details that I'd rather they were abstracted away from.

Comment: Ah, I see. Unfortunately there's no notion of a single "working directory" for all jobs submitted to a cluster where you'd specify relative paths for preexisting jars. The two approaches closest to what you're describing would be: 1. Jarfiles are local to the user's workspace - then gcloud automatically uploads at job-submission time into GCS and points the jarfile in a job-specific directory. 2. Use `--class` instead of `--jar`. I'll add these to the answer.