# NoClassDefFoundError com/microsoft/aad/adal4j/AuthenticationException while connecting to Azure SQL from GCP

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, azure-sql-database, google-cloud-dataproc

I have my spark project on data_proc in GCP, and on spark submit, running the driver program.
When I am trying to connect to Azure SQL DB, it is throwing the below exception:

```
20:39:15 DOCKER: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/aad/adal4j/AuthenticationException
20:39:15 DOCKER:    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getFedAuthToken(SQLServerConnection.java:3609)
20:39:15 DOCKER:    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.onFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:3580)
20:39:15 DOCKER:    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.processFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:3548)
20:39:15 DOCKER:    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onFedAuthInfo(tdsparser.java:261)
20:39:15 DOCKER:    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:103)
20:39:15 DOCKER:    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4290)
20:39:15 DOCKER:    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3157)
20:39:15 DOCKER:    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:82)
20:39:15 DOCKER:    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3121)
20:39:15 DOCKER:    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151)
20:39:15 DOCKER:    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478)
20:39:15 DOCKER:    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2026)
20:39:15 DOCKER:    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1687)
20:39:15 DOCKER:    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1528)
20:39:15 DOCKER:    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:866)
20:39:15 DOCKER:    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnectionInternal(SQLServerDataSource.java:968)
20:39:15 DOCKER:    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnection(SQLServerDataSource.java:69)
```

Below are the versions of the components :

- dataproc : 1.5
- adal4j : 1.6.7
- azure-sqldb-spark : 1.0.2

The authentication is via Active Directory.
The same thing works in local, but not in dataproc.
Appreciate any help!!

Comment: are you packaging all libraries into an uberjar?

Comment: @AlexOtt : Yes, it is a fat jar which will have all of the dependency, but I feel during runtime dataproc uses some other version of the jar

Comment: How are you actually submitting the spark job? Did you see [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62068707/where-should-i-put-jars-on-a-dataproc-cluster-so-they-can-be-used-by-gcloud-data)?

Comment: @jccampanero : I am using a custom image(not much different) to create the cluster. I even removed the init script and created the cluster after that.
The spark spark submit is of a vanilla flavour where I specified cluster, jar, region and properties

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback @SashiKant. Probably then your image contains some kind of dependency that it is causing the problem. Please, could you review this [Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark/issues/28), especially [this answer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark/issues/28#issuecomment-680341276)? It suggests the existence of an old mssql server dependency within the hadoop yarn libs that should be removed. In addition, although applicable to databricks, I think some of the suggestions provided in the issue could be valuable. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jccampanero : I tried searching for the mssql jar in my gcp space, but couldn't find it, may be some folders I am not having permission would have that.
Will try to update based on Igor's solution, Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @SashiKant. Sorry for the late reply. I am sorry to hear that you were unable to find the conflicting library. If you packed all your job code in a single jar, I think it is very likely that the problem will be related to a classpath conflict. I posted a possible alternative in an answer, although honestly I do not know if it will be relevant to your use case. I hope it helps any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are using Docker. If so you need to make sure that `adal4j.jar` is included in driver Docker container or it was added via `--jars` flag in Spark submit command:

```sh
gcloud dataproc jobs spark submit \
  --cluster-name $CLUSTER_NAME \
  . . . \
  --jars adal4j.jar
```

For reference, see how to manage Java dependencies in Spark: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/manage-spark-dependencies

Comment: Thanks for your answer, --jars option uses "The HCFS URI" how do I find that in my dataproc?
I will try adding the maven shaded plugin.
I am using dataproc 1.5, how can we know the hadoop version used there, can we upgrade it, as stated this issue is resolved in hadoop3.
Can you also please share the hadoop's relative lib location, from where the jars are being overridden ?

Comment: HCFS URI means that you can upload this jar in some GCS bucket and refer to it from there: `--jars=gs://$BUCKET/adal4j.jar`. That said, `--jars` flag in gcloud CLI also supports local files (it will upload local files to the cluster staging GCS bucket for you).

Comment: In the link which you have provided, it says even though we specify the jars during spark submit, it will still give preference to the libs hadoop refers to, can you help me with the path where hadoop 's dependencies are stored locally?

Comment: If you want to make some library available cluster-wide for all Spark jobs, for example, then you need to write an [init action](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/init-actions) that will download it to `/usr/lib/spark/jars/`directory during cluster creation on all cluster nodes. If your library will be available on all cluster nodes in `/usr/lib/spark/jars/` than you will not need to explicitly include it during your Spark job submission, but situations when you really need this are not very common.

Comment: I dont have any init action because this one is the only job at the moment, but still it is referring to the older versions of lib. I am not able to find where do i need to specifically go and remove.

Comment: May you add to the original questions description (preferably with code snippets) of how do you build and submit your job jar to Dataproc cluster?

Comment: Thanks Igor, resolved this with shade plugin

Comment: @SashiKant can you please share the steps to create the shaded plugin that helped in resolving this issue.

I'm trying to connect to AzSQL database using the mssql-jdbc connector using Dataproc cluster, the dependency jars are already provided while submitting the spark job, but i get the below error. The same code with dependencies worked in local.
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/aad/adal4j/AuthenticationException"

Answer (score 2):

If you packaged your job code as a fat jar with all its dependencies and you [submitted it appropriately](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/submit-job) to your Dataproc cluster, and even then you are facing the error, one possible reason of the problem is that a classpath conflict related to the SQL Server driver library exists somewhere. As pointed out as well in my comment, although in a different context, a similar behavior is reported in several Github issues like [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark/issues/28) or [this other](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector/issues/26).

In addition to trying removing the conflicting library, I do not know if applicable to your use case - probably not being a database driver - but perhaps you could try relocating the SQL Server code to a different package and use that package instead.

The approach is described in [the GCP Dataproc documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/manage-spark-dependencies), [for instance](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/manage-spark-dependencies#creating_a_shaded_uber_jar_with_maven), using the [Maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot JC, resolved it with shade plugin

Comment: You are welcome @SashiKant. I am very happy to hear that the solution proposed in the answer was helpful.