# NoClassDefFoundError while writing to Azure SQL using AD authetication in Dataproc cluster. But Works fine in Local

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, azure-sql-database, google-cloud-dataproc

I have written Spark Scala code. I have a strange issue where I am able to read successfully from Azure SQL using AD authentication in Dataproc cluster. But I am getting the below error while writing to Azure SQL.

```
NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/aad/adal4j/AuthenticationException
```

And I am getting this error **only while running in Dataproc cluster**. The same code works fine in my local machine.

Just to be more clear, I got the same error while reading too in Dataproc and I resolved it using  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70289697/noclassdeffounderror-com-microsoft-aad-adal4j-authenticationexception-while-conn) solution by using Maven shade plugin to relocate the conflicting library. But now again I am getting same error while writing. Not sure what is going wrong. Why is the write failing in Dataproc? Please help

**Code sample:**

Reading from Azure SQL(Working fine):

```
spark.read
      .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark")
      .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
      .option("encrypt", "false")
      .option("url", url)
      .option("database", database)
      .option("user", user)
      .option("password", password)
      .option("query",  query)
      .option("authentication", "ActiveDirectoryPassword")
      .load()
```

Writing to Azure SQL(Failing in Dataproc):

```
df.write
      .format("jdbc")
      .mode(mode)
      .option("url", url)
      .option("database", database)
      .option("user", user)
      .option("password", password)
      .option("dbtable",  table)
      .option("authentication", "ActiveDirectoryPassword")
      .save()
```

Maven Shade plugin:

```
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>com</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>repackaged.com.microsoft</shadedPattern>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>com.microsoft.**</include>
                                </includes>
                            </relocation>
```

Other Azure dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>msal4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mssql-connector_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding `.option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")` in write operation and it succeeded. Found the issue highlighted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver15)