# Getting adal4j/AuthenticationException while connecting to Azure SQL from Google Dataproc Cluster

Tags: java, sql-server, scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

Please hear me out.

I am able to successfully write to Azure SQL server table using [Apache Spark connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver16) in Dataproc cluster. But then while testing I found sometime that the SQL server database in not available and because of this the write operation fails.

So, I decided to add an exception logic to check if the database is available or not using the following code before writing to Azure DB,

```
    var connection: Connection = null
    val url = "jdbc:sqlserver://***.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=some_db;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword"
    val user = "xxxx"
    val password = ******
    try
          {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)
            log.info(s"Successfully established connection on attempt: "+attempts)
            return
          }
```

**This code works fine in my local machine. But while running the same in Dataproc I am getting the below error,**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/aad/adal4j/AuthenticationException
```

I already went though this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70289697/noclassdeffounderror-com-microsoft-aad-adal4j-authenticationexception-while-conn) discussed in SO. But it's bit different for me as the  Apache Spark connector to write to SQL server is working fine. I just want to have the code `DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)` work to test the connection before my write.

Comment: Did you read through the [Commonly Faced Issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector#commonly-faced-issues) section of the Apache Spark Connector page you linked initially?

Comment: Yes. As I said there is no issue with Spark Connector. It works fine while writing the data.